# System.IO.FileMode.Open

Tags: c#

For my system, i first need to read CSV file and then i need to connect to the database in SQL server 2008 according to the data in .ini file.

I use System.IO.FileStream() to read file. There is no problem to open and read data.

But, when i read csv file and then connect to the database , i cant access to the .ini file 
because System.IO.FileStream() function take the path of ini file like as the location of csv file.

So, when i read csv file from Desktop , System.IO.FileStream() function search the ini file in Desktop and when i read from My Document, it search in My Document.

Thus, i want to know how to control this.

My function to read ini file : System.IO.FileStream("fileNameOnly", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your `OpenFileDialog.RestoreDirectory` to True to have the dialog reset its location on each use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.Now i can clear the old file path.